# Make div stay in one place no matter how matter the height of the page

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have two div's that I want to have equal height. The left div has dynamic content which can expand vertically with any number of inner div's. The right div has one inner div that needs to stay at the top and still be visible no matter how far you scroll down. Please look at this codepen

```css
#shipping_policies {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    padding: 5px;
}

#shipping_policies a {
    display: block;
    font-size: .9em;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.checkout .card-header {
    background-color: #f2f2f2 !important;
}

.checkout button {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 0.6em;
}

.square1 {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    line-height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}

.square1 p {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container mt-5 h-auto">
  <div class="" style="">
    <div class="col-6 border-danger float-left d-inline-block mr-1" style="background-color: #ffffff;">
      <div style="width: 150px;" class="py-2 d-inline">
        <div class="float-left">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/228x150" alt="" class="mt-2 mb-5" /><br>
          <a class="mt-4" style="border-radius: 0; width: 150px; margin-bottom: 10px;" id="del-item" href="#">X REMOVE</a>
        </div>
        <div class="float-left ml-3 mt-1">
          <p class="px-0 mb-0">short_desc</p>
          <p class="px-0 mb-0">UOM</p>
          <label for="quantity" style="margin-bottom: 0; font-weight: bold; margin-top: 20px;">QTY</label><br>
          <input type="text" class="quantity" name="quantity" value="1">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div style="position: absolute; right: 10px; bottom: 1px;">
        <p class="mb-0" style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 1.1em; color: #990000;">$399.99</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 border-danger float-left d-inline-block mr-1" style="background-color: #ffffff;">
      <div style="width: 150px;" class="py-2 d-inline">
        <div class="float-left">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/228x150" alt="" class="mt-2 mb-5" /><br>
          <a class="mt-4" style="border-radius: 0; width: 150px; margin-bottom: 10px;" id="del-item" href="#">X REMOVE</a>
        </div>
        <div class="float-left ml-3 mt-1">
          <p class="px-0 mb-0">short_desc</p>
          <p class="px-0 mb-0">UOM</p>
          <label for="quantity" style="margin-bottom: 0; font-weight: bold; margin-top: 20px;">QTY</label><br>
          <input type="text" class="quantity" name="quantity" value="1">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div style="position: absolute; right: 10px; bottom: 1px;">
        <p class="mb-0" style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 1.1em; color: #990000;">$399.99</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="" style="">
    <div class="col-4 border-danger float-left ml-4" style="background-color: #f2f2f2; border-radius: 4px;">
      <div class="w-100 mt-2">
        <span>Subtotal</span>
        <p class="float-right">$399.99</p>
      </div>
      <div class="w-100 mt-4">
        <h4 style="font-weight: bold; margin-bottom: 0">Estimated Total</h4>
        <p class="float-right" style="font-size: large; font-weight: bold;">$399.99</p>
        <p class="" style="font-size: smaller">Tax Calculated at Checkout</p>
      </div>
      <hr style="height: 2px; color: #000; background: #000;" />
      <div class="w-100">
        <input class="w-100" style="height: 40px;" type="text" id="promo" name="promo" placeholder="Enter Promo Code" />
        <button style="position: absolute; right: 8%; bottom: 34%; background-color: #0066CC; color: #FFFFFF;">Apply Now</button>
      </div>
      <hr style="height: 5px; color: #000; background: #0066CC;" />
      <a class="w-100 mb-2 btn" style="background-color: #febd69;" href="http://groves.local/product/checkout">CHECKOUT</a>
    </div>
    <div class="float-right" style="margin-right: 15%; margin-top: 2%; width: 340px;">
      <h5 style="font-weight: bold;">Shipping &amp; Policies</h5>
      <div id="shipping_policies">
        <a href="#">Shipping</a>
        <a href="#">Policies</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<div>
```

This code snippet is where I have gotten so far any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added a class `.fixed` with `position:fixed` to the element that should stay on one place, also fixed your html layout. See https://codepen.io/anon/pen/joYmvV?editors=1100

Update:
You can also add `position:sticky` instead of `position:fixed` - It produces a nice effect. See the updated code https://codepen.io/anon/pen/joYmvV?editors=1100

Comment: That's fixed the fixed one thing and broke the left div. Thanks for the input it gave me a good starting point thanks.

Comment: I recommend you use `position: sticky` instead of `position: fixed` on the right div, so that width and positioning gets inherited from the parent div with `class="col-sm-4"`

Comment: @EricEvans the left div shouldn't get affected since it has `class="col-sm-8"`

Comment: Look that this left side div it should look like this. https://codepen.io/gork4life1/pen/vwWRqZ

Comment: @EricEvans I see what you mean. It was caused by the col-X classes that you applied. See the updated code https://codepen.io/anon/pen/joYmvV?editors=1100

Comment: this is close but now the price on the left div are stacked on top of each other.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193776/discussion-between-eric-evans-and-kabelo-tooka).

Answer (score 0):

Use position fixed. Position fixed makes it so that an element stays at it's specified place even if the user scrolls up or down.

Comment: See how the right div is down to second level div, how can I bring that up to first level div?

Comment: I used the position fixed and that works for the most part still playing with it got it almost to where I need it.